# Android - alternative for OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I need to make a image recognition app. I was going through OpenCV tutorial and it says i need to install OpenCV manager from Google play which i think is not good from a user point of view. But after digging for many hours i noticed that OpenCV is the most popular and reliable among all. Is there any good alternative to OpenCV which does not require an another app to be installed. And what is this static initialisation of OpenCV. And if i do not want to install OpenCV manager then how good should I know NDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static initialisation is the alternative to the OpenCV manager, with it the library is included within the apk (like in the past) and the user does not need to install the manager. Also the devs are working on making the Manager-way of deploying apps more smooth to the users.

Comment: Ok here is one more question. If i do the static initialisation what files do i need to add in my lib folder. OpenCV tutorial gave me a blur picture of how it works. I checked files inside native/libs and these are some huge files in terms of size which i am not going to add at all. How they can have an app OpenCV manager of 375kb doing all the stuff that requires megs of files. I think i am confused. Could you explain little bit more that what files from that lib folder would i require to make things work in my app.

Comment: sorry for asking newbie stuff but i never done anything like this before.

Comment: OpenCV manager is 375kb because it will prompt you to download a lib of a few MB that depends on the CPU of your smartphone. You have to include manually that lib when you do the static method. From those "huge" files you have to choose the one right for the target devices or include them all. I think if you include them all your app will not go over 25Mb, right?

Comment: Yeah right and thanks for your valuable reply. I did exactly what their tutorial said and my app is almost 9mb. Its 9mb cuz i only included the package required for my device. I think i will drop this idea as this app is just for fun not a serious stuff. I am accepting your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can ship OpenCV in your own package if you want, you don't really need for the manager. If you ship OpenCV in your package you can use it at native level (C/C++), but you can also use the wrappers for using it directly at Java level.

Comment: IMPORTANT : OpenCV manager contains a native opencv library compiled with gnustl_static... In case your C++ code is compiled with gnustl_static as well, this may result in horrible crashes!!! just read the "Static runtimes" section of CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html in docs page of the NDK

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a library of Qualcomm [Vuforia](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality). I have never used it but I heard about it a lot.

Comment: Vuforia is big AR stuff. i can not add that much overhead in my app but still thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess nowadays pure Java solution for image processing is [BoofCV](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Their site contains number of tutorials you could adopt for your needs =)